# How to enable https on bluemix with docker-compose

Tags: https, containers, ibm-cloud, docker-compose

I created a simple application consisting of nginx and python flask made up of two containers, which I can deploy to bluemix using docker-compose.

The docker compose file is *docker-compose-bluemix.yml*

```
flask:
  image: registry.ng.bluemix.net/namespace/simple.flask
  restart: always
  expose:
    - "8000"
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 2 -b :8000 app:app

nginx:
  image: registry.ng.bluemix.net/namespace/simple.nginx
  restart: always
  ports:
      - "80:80"
  links:
    - flask:flask
```

Once I assign an ip to the nginx container it works, in that I can access it like so,

```
curl http://ip/flask-api/v0.01/hello
```

and the correct response is returned

```
{"status": "hello"}
```

How do I enable https for this app? Must it be done by providing the nginx container self signed certs, or can I leverage bluemix to give me a *https://xxx.mybluemix.net* address for the containers? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

If you want Bluemix to assign a route like https://xxx.mybluemix.net then you need to deploy a **Scalable Group** instead of a **Single Container**. Scalable Groups can be assigned routes which will allow SSL (https://) access.

I don't believe that you can do this with Docker Compose because Docker is not aware of the container group capabilities in Bluemix. You could use the IBM Container extensions to the Cloud Foundry CLI to do this from the command line or from your DevOps pipeline tool of choice with the following commands:

```
cf ic group create --name simple-flask -m 64 -p 8000 --min 1 --max 3 --desired 2 registry.ng.bluemix.net/namespace/simple-flask:latest
cf ic route map -n simple-flask -d mybluemix.net simple-flask
```

At that point you don't need `nginx` because Bluemix will put a load balancer in front of your container group for you to direct traffic to the containers within it. You can then get to it via:

```
https://simple-flask.mybluemix.net/flask-api/v0.01/hello
```

This should give you what you were looking for.

~jr